EEVEE Render sometimes makes all objects blue
Blender newbie here.
I'm trying to render my nice new animation, but some frames are just showing the outlines of objects instead of the objects themselves.
It seems to happen every 5th or 10th frame; it's not always the same frame.
Update: It seems to work just fine on my "upstairs" machine, an itty bitty Dell Latitude T7250 running Ubuntu 20.04.
I'm not sure if it's a symptom, but the upper left corner of the frames has a black patch.
Rendering a 960x540 frame takes about two seconds.
I'm running Blender 4.2.3 LTS, Ubuntu 24.04.
Video card is an AMD Cape Verde PRO [Radeon HD 7750/8740 / R7 250E]
The animation has two objects -- a disk for the ground, and an airplane that's modeled as five spheres stretched and squashed and located to look airplane-like.
I'm generating positions for the airplane offline, then generating keyframes for the airplane from them and applying them to the airplane only.  One keyframe for every fifth frame.
In answer to the comment -- I haven't explicitly added textures to any objects -- but it usually renders.  Having looked at the texture tool, I don't see anything that looks like a "just a plain old texture".  Do I need to add something specific?  What's a good "plain old" texture?
Any clues to what this could be?



That’s not blue, it’s “texture missing” violet, and it could be appearing for any number of reasons. My first guess is that you’ve got an animated image, sequence, texture, and one of the frames is missing, or it’s set to look for too many frames. Please add further details about what’s happening in the animation data-wise.

Oh, color-coded errors.  This color-blind person is overjoyed to know that.

Blender doesn’t use colors alone to represent any other kind of error afaik.  They all have an X or an exclamation mark.

That's comforting.

What does “generating keyframes offline” mean?

There isn’t a “texture tool,” but default materials should work without error. Might be time to share your blend file via blend-exchange.com if you can. Meanwhile, here’s an explanation of textures and materials.

I reworded my tidbit about the keyframes.

@TimWescott The dev team pointed out during BCon24 that Blender UI will stay mostly monochromatic, with some rare colors here and there. Remember you can change all UI colors in settings if needed.

@Lutzi: I'm rendering to frames -- yes, the UI is monochromatic and that's fine, but that has nothing to do with my problem.

Okay, working on some systems but not others with the same version of Blender is either a config problem or a bug. Double check that they are the same version, then try launching the problematic one with factory defaults and see if that fixes it. If not, file a bug report for Blender.
